# Can't get Ehcache to work with spring 3

Tags: spring, security, ehcache

I am new to Spring so please forgive me if my question is foolish...

I am trying to follow some examples for configuring security on a spring web application. I have configured it to work with ldap directory. Now I need to add caching to the process so that the credentials are not fetched from the ldap directory every time they are requested.

For this I have added `cache-ref="userCache"` as shown in the tutorial:

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
     ...
    <ldap-user-service server-ref="ldapServer"
       user-search-filter="uid={0}" user-search-base="ou=people"
       group-search-filter="member={0}" group-search-base="ou=groups"
       cache-ref="userCache" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The bean `userCache` is defined like this :

```
 <beans:bean id="userCache"             
    class="org.springframework.security.providers.
    dao.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache">
    <beans:property name="cache" ref="userEhCache" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="userEhCache"
     class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
     <beans:property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
     <beans:property name="cacheName" value="userCache" />
 </beans:bean>
```

The cache manager is defined as follows:

```
  <bean id="cacheManager"
   class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
```

The problem with this configuration is that I couldn't get the jars because they are based on an old version of spring 2.  The cache manager I got it using

```
 <bean id="cacheManager"
 class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" />
```

but the `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean`  and `org.springframework.security.providers.dao.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache` I don't know where to get them beside from spring 2 which if I add to my project it brakes everything.

I would appreciate any help in this matter. If you have some other solution please make some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring 3.0.x `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean` is located in *spring-context-support-3.0.x.RELEASE.jar*.

There is no class `org.springframework.security.providers.dao.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache` but there is class `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache` located in *spring-security-core-3.0.x.RELEASE.jar*.